# Tomcat webserver is not logging any DEBUG or FINEST logs in catalina.out even after enabling FINEST in logging.proprties file(tomcat-8.5.79/conf/)

Tags: java, tomcat

I am facing an issue in Linux server that webserver service is restarting automatically frequently. I tried to enable debug logs by changing the all logging properties in tomcat-8.5.79/conf/logging.proprties. But I see only INFO logs but no FINE or FINER or FINEST logs.

**logging.properties**

```
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
 
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
 
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8
 
    ############################################################
    # Facility specific properties.
    # Provides extra control for each logger.
    ############################################################

    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINEST
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = FINEST
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 
    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = FINEST
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

**catalina.out**

```
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe638000368, pid=54728, tid=0x00007fe625309700
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_333-b31) (build 1.8.0_333-b31)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.333-b31 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  0x00007fe638000368
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /tmp/hs_err_pid54728.log
    [thread 140626492360448 also had an error]
    [thread 140626582980352 also had an error][thread 140626573510400 also had an error][thread 140626420045568 also had an error][thread 140626442094336 also had an error]
    
    
    
    [thread 140626437883648 also had an error]
    [thread 140626548127488 also had an error][thread 140626414782208 also had an error][thread 140626567083776 also had an error]
    
    
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server} Setting property 'command' to 'SHUTDOWN' did not find a matching property.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.AbcGlobalResourcesLifecycleListener 
    INFO: AbcUserDatabaseMbean descriptor loaded
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          May 16 2022 15:36:23 UTC
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version number: 0.0.0.0
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Linux
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /abc/sw/runtime/jdk1.8.0_333/jre
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_333-b31
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx512M
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DHEAP_SIZE=512M
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dpname=WebServer
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/abc/sw/runtime/tomcat
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/abc/sw/runtime/tomcat
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/abc/sw/runtime/tomcat/temp
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DLOG_DIR=/abc/log/sw_log
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DCONF_DIR=/abc/sw/conf
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -DRT_DIR=/abc/sw/runtime
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///abc/sw/platform/common-R29H01_EC01b1486/dclib/common.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/engine-R32H01_EC05b3632/dclib/engine.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/licensing-R26G01b491/dclib/licensing.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/scheduler-R25H04b525/dclib/scheduler.jar file:///abc/sw/platform/symboliclinkcreator-R19H09_EC02b369/dclib/symboliclinkcreator.jar
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/adminui/conf/adminui.properties
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 678 ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM com.abcdef.catalina.users.AbcUserDatabaseFactory getObjectInstance
    INFO: ABC UserDatabase successfully created.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/ROOT]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [616] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/host-manager]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [53] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/manager]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/manager] has finished in [56] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/adminui]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/adminui] has finished in [1,244] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/alarmcfg]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/alarmcfg] has finished in [13,051] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/universeupdateinstaller]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/abc/sw/runtime/apache-tomcat-8.5.79/webapps/universeupdateinstaller] has finished in [274] ms
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
    Jun 01, 2023 9:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 15359 ms
```